# Can't unlock preferences - no password dialog

Tags: macos, system-settings

In system preferences, if I click the "lock" icon to allow me to make changes as the administrator, no dialog opens.  The message "Authenticating..." appears momentarily, then disappears, and the lock stays locked.

I'm on OS X 10.6.8.

Any idea what could cause this or how to fix it?

Comment: Are you an administrator, regular/limited user, or guest user?

Comment: Administrator..

Answer (score 5):

I've had this same issue for months. Before it was my old MBP since "upgrading" from Snow Leopard to Lion, and now again on my brand new MBP with Mountain Lion.  After some digging it looks like a fairly common problem, possibly to do with CAC/ID card readers.

Anyway, this worked for me (without a reboot!). From Terminal:

```
sudo pkill -HUP securityd
```

When I did this Mail apparently lost it's connection to the security framework and started prompting me for passwords; I just restarted it and it was good to go.

Comment: Interesting - I'd like to try this, but I already fixed my problem by deleting all of my preferences and rebooting.  I'll try next time around...

Comment: Hm. I wish that worked for me.  Deleting my prefs and rebooting did nothing, so it's either because we have different environments or different problems entirely. Oh well.

Comment: It worked for me without rebooting!

Comment: +1 worked also for me. And yes, my problem is related to CAC/ID card reader (Estonian ID card). So I can confirm that this solution works if your issues are also related to CAC/ID card reader. FYI: I'm on OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: BTW, "pkill" is not available on OSX by default (at least not on 10.7.5), you can use "killall" for the same purpose: sudo killall -HUP securityd

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as an issue either with *permissions* or *keychains*. Try repairing them both.

To check Keychains for problems just:

1. Locate the **Keychain Access** application, under **/Applications/Utilities**.
2. Choose **Keychain Access > Keychain First Aid**.
3. Enter your User name and Password.
4. Select *Verify* and click *Start*.
5. If any problems were found, select *Repair* and click *Start* again.

Comment: That's great to know about it.  I did the verify & repair (though nothing was reported to be wrong), but unfortunately it did not fix (or in any way change) the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has something to do with `authd`. You can just kill or force `authd` to quit like this (in Terminal on Mavericks):

```
sudo pkill -HUP authd
```

(when prompted, type your password.)

Just killing `securityd` doesn't work on Mavericks.

Answer (score 0):

I has the same as original problem after latest update to 10.10.3
killing the authd as this:

```
sudo pkill -HUP authd
```

and checking with the terminal and 'ps -ef | egrep "authd|securityd" showed that is was restarted immediately. But this did not change the behavior.

Then I tried the same with the target of securityd,

```
sudo pkill -HUP securityd
```

afterwards, it is still not running, but then I did not check before hand and so I don't know whether it WAS running previously. But there is a new behaviour>

When I click the lock icon to unlock access to change the Sys Preferences, it does NOT respond at all - no brief message about authenticating.

That what I get for poking around in the dark :-)

A system reboot will be happening as soon as convenient (reach a good stopping point).

Answer (score 0):

My Security & Privacy wouldn't unlock either. I had no password set on my account when this was happening. I went to Accounts and set an arbitrary password and I was able to finally unlock the pane. Afterward, I just reset the password back to being no password.